# How to count number of values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman, postman-testcase

I am trying to count the values a json array.

I want to count the number of id's in the data array of "sierra" if "beta = b". Hence checking the value of data[].beta against the environment variable ("B") set to value 'b'.

The issue here is I do not have "sierra" in every iteration of data[].

```
{
  "data": [{
        "alpha": "a",
        "beta": "b",
        "delta": {
            "cat": "dog"
        },
        "gamma": {
            "sierra": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "alphabet",
                        "id": "a"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "alphabet",
                        "id": "b"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
   },
{
        "alpha": "a",
        "beta": "b",
        "delta": {
            "cat": "dog"
        },
        "bravo": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "number",
                        "id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "number",
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
   },
{
        "alpha": "x",
        "beta": "y",
        "delta": {
            "cat": "dog"
        },
        "gamma": {
            "sierra": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "alphabet",
                        "id": "c"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "alphabet",
                        "id": "d"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
   }]
}
```

Above json is the response body I see in postman. "loop" is the count of my "for" loop.

EDIT 1:
I've tried this:

```
1. pm.response.json().data[loop].gamma.sierra.data().id).size()

2. for(var loop =0; loop < pm.response.json().data.length; loop++)
{
 if(pm.response.json().data[loop].beta===pm.variables.get("B"))
{      
        pm.response.json().data.map((item, loop) => {
            if(item.gamma){ // check if gamma key is present
                console.log(item.gamma.sierra.filter(data =>data.id 
                                                      ).length); // 
            }
        });
        result=true;
        break;

    }
}
pm.expect(true).to.eql(result);
```

Expected: 2

```
Actual: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sierra' of undefined
Actual: item.relationships.apps.filter is not a function
```

Comment: What is `loop` in your code ?

Comment: You can find it by pm.response.json().data[loop].gamma.sierra.data().length

Comment: Try logging in `pm.response.json().data[loop]` first. It appears that one or few of the `data[loop]` is missing the `gamma` key.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut I guess he is running a loop and `loop` is the index number.

Comment: You attempt to call a function that does not exist: .sierra.data(). In your casa data is just an array.

Comment: @Nuhman Yes. I do not have the "gamma" in every .data[loop]. Actually the response json is quite big. Didn't post the entire thing here.

Comment: @Siva okay so that's exactly why you run into this error. You need to check for `gamma` key existence before you try to access further contents. Add an `if` check or something on top.

Comment: @Nuhman I am trying it like this. This is the block of code I am using. 

    for(var loop =0; loop < pm.response.json().data.length; loop++)
      {
    if(pm.response.json().data[loop].gamma !== null){
        console.log(pm.response.json().data[loop].gamma.sierra.data().id.length);
            }
            result=true;
            break;
    } 

I am at a loss. Quite new to this stuff.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. could you please take a look and let me know now? I've edited the question.

Comment: @Nuhman could you please take a look and let me know now? I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a dynamic apporach and hand over the key of the object where you like to count a certain inner key.

```js
function count(object, key, subKey) {
    const noObject = o => !o || typeof o !== 'object';

    function subCount(object) {
        if (noObject(object)) return 0;
        if (subKey in object) return 1;
        return Object.values(object).reduce((s, o) => s + subCount(o), 0);
    }

    if (noObject(object)) return 0;
    if (key in object) return subCount(object[key]);
    return Object.values(object).reduce((s, o) => s + count(o, key, subKey), 0);
}

var data = { data: [{ alpha: "a", beta: "b", delta: { cat: "dog" }, gamma: { sierra: { data: [{ type: "alphabet", id: "a" }, { type: "alphabet", id: "b" }] } } }] };

console.log(count(data, 'sierra', 'id')); // 2
```

Comment: This works for me :-) Thanks a ton! Could you please explain the logic behind this please? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: it checks if a key exists and hands over to subCount or iterates all values and make a recursive call to `count`. if the key is foind, it looks for a wanted (sub) key and counts it by returning one.

Comment: This is literally the only solution I could find in a full day!

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this. If you have multiple data records you can use each loop to calculate as well.

```js
a = {
 "data": [ 
 {
        "alpha": "a",
        "beta": "b",
        "delta": {
            "cat": "dog"
        },
        "gamma": {
            "sierra": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "alphabet",
                        "id": "a"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "alphabet",
                        "id": "b"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}

console.log(a.data[0].gamma.sierra.data.length);
```

Comment: Apparently I did not make my question clear. Now I've edited with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

`pm.response.json().data[0].gamma.sierra.data.filter( d => d.id ).length`

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is "d" here? Could you please explain?

Comment: filter actually loops through data array and `d` just means the current element in the loop.

Comment: `d => d.id` means `function whatecer(d){ return d.id }` its basically a callback called on every array element - it checks if it has `id` and if it does it passes an element further to `.length`

Answer (score 0):

```js
pm.response.json().data.map((item, loop) => {
    if(item.beta === "b" && item.gamma){ // check if gamma key is present

        console.log(item.gamma.sierra.data.filter(data => data.id).length); // 
    }
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLj7t95p/1/)

Comment: TypeError: item.gamma.filter is not a function

Comment: This works but it gives the count of every sierra I have. 
I added the if loop to your code like this.  

`if(pm.response.json().data[loop].id===pm.variables.get("B")){ //your code here }`

Still it gives the count as 2, 2. It does not seem to differentiate.

Comment: Remove your outer 'for' loop and check the updated code

Comment: It isn't going into the `if(item.gamma)` loop!

Comment: uhm, so what exactly is "loop" doing here? Is that the substitute of "for" loop?

Comment: No. It actually corresponds to the index of the loop like 0,1,2 etc. which we're not using here. So you may remove the `loop` keyword if you feel like. The closest 'substitute' of foor loop in this code is actually `map`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195685/discussion-between-siva-and-nuhman).