# Want to know meaning of this piece of code

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I saw this block of code here [How to count number of values in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56785331/how-to-count-number-of-values-in-array/56785473#56785473). As a solution for my other question.

This solves my issue but I do not want to use it without knowing what it means. Can someone give me a detailed explanation of this code?

```
function count(object, key, subKey) {
  const noObject = o => !o || typeof o !== 'object';

  function subCount(object) {
    if (noObject(object)) return 0;
    if (subKey in object) return 1;

    return Object.values(object).reduce((s, o) => s + subCount(o), 0);
  }

  if (noObject(object)) return 0;
  if (key in object) return subCount(object[key]);

  return Object.values(object).reduce((s, o) => s + count(o, key, subKey), 0);
}
```

Is this used to count the number of values in a JSON array?

Comment: What is not clear in particular?

Comment: The line 2 and the return statement.

Comment: It's an (somewhat) awkward way of writing a recursive traversal that counts the number of properties in an object that are objects.

Comment: Yeah found this piece of code when trying to figure out how to count the values in my POSTMAN response body json.

Comment: The first line can be read as `const noObject = function (o) { return !o || typeof o !== 'object';}` if it makes it more clear. It returns true if `o` is not an object

Comment: It'd be easier to make sense of it is what better laid out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a deep object counter - so it'll count how many values in an object are themselves objects. It returns `1` if the key(s) you pass are in the object, `0` if the object is not an object, and any other number (including `0` and `1`, confusingly) which will be the number of objects.

The second line is an arrow function, and returns a Boolean if the passed `object` is either falsy or not an object.

The `return` statement (the last one) goes through each value in the object, and gets the count of each item. And since both `subCount` and `count` are recursive, this may go into multiple recursion levels.

<sub>(It's also a fairly unconventional and low-performance way to write this function IMHO.)</sub>

Comment: I just have No to little idea what this piece of code does. Just put it here so that I could get some help

Disheartened with the all the downvotes tbh.